# Can github desktop be configured to ignore untracked files

Tags: github

Is it possible to configure the github desktop client to show only files that are in the repo, same as what `gitk` seems to do by default, or similar to running `git status --untracked-files=no` from the command line?

In some repository directories there are a ton of untracked files that I don't want to delete or add to .gitignore, I just want to 'hide' them when I'm diffing the important files. (I use github desktop only to review changes, not to push or create PRs.)

Answer (score 1):

GitHub desktop is initially not designed to hide all untracked files in a working branch. Unfortunately there is neither a workaround for doing this. Here is the link that talks about adding this change as an update in its future releases.

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3734